# Multithreading makes my code having some issues

Tags: python, multithreading

I have tried to implement multithreading into a tool I've written, but I'm getting unexpected results.

Here is the working code:

```
#Import modules
import os
import time
import sys


#Params
print("___________Auto ShutApp___________\n")

print("Type the AppName then the time before app will shut")

apptokill = str(input("\nWhich App you'd like to Shut: "))
Time = int(input("\nHow long before App should stop(in minutes): "))



def timeS(arg):         #arg = time in seconds
    time.sleep(arg*60)



def killer(apptokill, Time):
    timeS(Time)
    os.system("pkill %s"%(apptokill))


killer(apptokill, Time)
```

This works fine, but I wanted to know when it would kill an app so I added a new function

```
def Timer():
    time_start = time.time()
    seconds = 0
    minutes = 0

    while True:
        try:
            sys.stdout.write("\rTimer have start since {minutes} Minutes {seconds} Seconds".format(minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
            seconds = int(time.time() - time_start) - minutes * 60
            if seconds >= 60:
                minutes += 1
                seconds = 0
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

This one also works well, but if I place the function it will run either `killer` or `Timer` - not both.

I then tried some mutlithreading, adding the code below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=killer, name='t1')
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=Timer, name='t2')

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

but from this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: killer() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'apptokill' and 'Time'
```

I assumed `apptokill` is saved in memory and so `Time` as well. I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide arguments to `killer`

When calling by hand you are doing it like this

```
killer(apptokill, Time)
```

When starting `killer` in a thread it still needs to know what to use as arguments. The solution would look like this:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=killer, name='t1', args=(apptokill, Time))
```